# Chrome stopping default behavior of click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

All I find when I google this is the opposite.
I have this jquery for disabling form buttons after they were clicked once.

```
$('.btn').click(function (event) {
    $(event.target).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

In Firefox (after adding `autocomplete="off"` because of [this "feature"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072)) and IE this works as intended, the button is disabled but the form action is also performed, restricting the user form clicking it more than once. However in Chrome it stops the event propagation by itself, and I cannot find how to make it not do that.

Comment: have you tried just to delay it: `setTimeout(function(){$(event.target).prop("disabled", true);},0);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the form submission like that:

```
$(event.target).prop("disabled", true).closest("form").trigger("submit");
```